# Python -> How do I loop through a determined list by five or ten or 20?

Tags: python, range

I am running python 3.6 and I made this script with help of a friend. But now we stopped in this problems. We would like the RANGE make multiples of any number we wish...

we know that:

for i in xrange(0,10,2):
  print(i)

So it would print 2, 4, 6... but with our script, for some reason, we cannot to put the STEP.... what are we doing wrong?

Below is the script:

```
try:
    start = 5000
    end = 50000
    for i in range(start, end): 
        url = 'https://testesite.com/Fatura/Pdf?nrFatura='+str(i).zfill(len(str(end)))
        print(url)
        q.put(url)
    q.join()
```

from the start 5000 till 50000, we would like to make it step 5 or 10 or any number we wish... example...

step with 5 = would run a loop from 5005 5010 5015
 step with 100 = would run a loop from 5100 5200 5300

How to include that function here ?

thank you

Comment: Why doesn't     `for i in range(start, end, step):`  work?

Comment: i tried the code from @Akshay Nevrekar below, but i got a error... what are we doing wrong ?? we are confuse too. it shoudl work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need

```
try:
    start = 5000
    end = 50000
    step = 10  # define the interval here
    for i in range(start, end, step): 
        url = 'https://testesite.com/Fatura/Pdf?nrFatura='+str(i).zfill(len(str(end)))
        print(url)
        q.put(url)
    q.join()
```

Comment: for some reason, it doesnt work. we get this return  File "teste.py", line 46
    step = 10
            ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @ALessandro That is a completely unrelated error to using `step`

Comment: That's an issue with your indentations. Use either tabs or spaces in your code. Don't mix them.

Comment: you were right, but another crazy thing happem. It is now runningm but the incresed number is not corret, we get this increase: =020184001100976
/Pdf?nrFatura=020184001101276
/Pdf?nrFatura=020184001101076
/Pdf?nrFatura=020184001101376
/Pdf?nrFatura=020184001101176

Comment: we putted from range 20184001100076 to 201840017800000 and we would like to get the increase in the end... but for some reason, it is increasing in the begin and in the middle

Comment: see the range we are getting   020184001100076
020184001100176
020184001100276
020184001100376
020184001100476
020184001100576
020184001100676
020184001100776
020184001100876
020184001100976
020184001101076
020184001101176
020184001101276
020184001101376
020184001101476
020184001101576
020184001101676
020184001101776
020184001101876
020184001101976
020184001102076
020184001102176
020184001102276
020184001102376
020184001102476
020184001102576
020184001102676
020184001102776
020184001102876
020184001102976
020184001103076

Comment: I don't see any issue here. Value is increasing by 100 each time what it suppose to do.

Comment: but it is increasing a "0" in the begin... the corret is 20184001102176... and it it putting 020184001102176, understand ?? why ?? we cannot to get this ZERO in the begin.. or the url will be wrong

Comment: how would we fix this small issue, not allowing to increase the zero (0) in the begin of the number ?? sorry for all newbie questions.. still learning

Comment: I'm not getting the zero at the start. Maybe you can post it as new question. It has to do something with your editor settings.

Comment: the code is exactly this: try:
    start = 20184001100076
    end = 201840017800000
    step = 10
    for i in range(start, end,step): 
        url = 'https://teste.com/Fatura/Pdf?nrFatura='+str(i).zfill(len(str(end)))
        print(url)
        q.put(url)
    q.join()
, but I keep getting the zero in the begin of the number..

Comment: @Akshay Nevrekar -> I found the error !! very simples. You are totaly right !! Thank you very much